# SwiftUI @EnvironmentObject: Not Found?

Tags: swiftui

I have a struct that I want to turn into an EnvironmentObject so I can pass it to a child struct, but when I do, it crashes by saying `MissingEnvironmentObjectError: Missing EnvironmentObject`. My struct looks like:

```
class event: ObservableObject {
    @Published var Name: String
    @Published var CalendarID: Int
    var timeStart: Date
    var timeEnd: Date
    var checklist = [checklistObject]()
    
    init(_ eventName: String, _ calID: Int, _ timeStart: Date, _ timeEnd: Date) {
        Name = eventName
        CalendarID = calID
        self.timeStart = timeStart
        self.timeEnd = timeEnd
        logger.log("Successfully created new event")
    }
    
    func newChecklistItem(Content: String){
        checklist.append(checklistObject(Content, false))
    }
    
    func getChecklistSize() -> Int {
        return checklist.count
    }
}
```

and my program looks like:

```
import SwiftUI

struct checklistDisplayRow: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var Event: event
    var itemID: Int
    
    init(itemID: Int){
        self.itemID = itemID
        Event.newChecklistItem(Content: "Stuff")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Toggle("", isOn: $Event.checklist[itemID].complete)
            Text("hi")
        }
    }
}

struct checklistDisplayRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        checklistDisplayRow(itemID: 0)
            .environmentObject(event("Title", 1, Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1576800000), Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1576800060)))
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you are setting the environment object for the preview, but you also need to set it in the hierarchy above where you are using `checklistDisplayRow`.

For example, if you were using a few `checklistDisplayRow`s in a `VStack` (for the items in an event's checklist), you could do something like this:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(checklist, id: \.id) { item in
        checklistDisplayRow(itemID: item.id)
    }
}.environmentObject(
    event("Title", 1, Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1576800000), Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1576800060)
)
```

I hope that's helpful!